# intellisense for XSD query in ASP.NET which returns different schema

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, xsd

I have an xsd query returning a different schema than the table it's associated with. How can I define a row in my vb code which would give me the intellisense for that special schema?

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, I only had one extra field in the schema that wasn't in the associated table. Therefore, I declared a variable with the xsd row object and was able to get the extra value using the .item(index) to get that extra field. I had thought that the item would not be available at all.